# Change PC local group members from Active Directory Domain Controller?

Tags: windows, active-directory, user-groups

Our environment is based on a Windows Server 2003, and more than a hundred computers in the domain.

These computers have the usual domain user in the local Administrator group of the respective computer.

Is there a way to remove them remotely, lets say, from the Domain Controller?

Also we need to remove them from another group which controls access to antivirus configuration, so we need to remove them from both.

Comment: In "remove them": who exactly is them? The domain user that is added to the local admins group? Is it always the same user name or is this different for different client PCs?

Comment: You're looking for [restricted groups](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20402.active-directory-group-policy-restricted-groups.aspx) ([more](http://www.windowsecurity.com/articles-tutorials/windows_os_security/Using-Restricted-Groups.html)) Hopefully someone will write up an actual answer. ;)

Comment: So far, I'm removing them manually, AD users and computers-> domain-> Computers. Selecting each one, right click, Admin...

Answer (score -1):

Yes. When a computer is joined to a domain, it becomes possible to remotely manage it.

From a server, go to Start->Administrative Tools->Computer Management.

Click on the top left where it says Local Computer. Now right-click this, and select "Connect to remote computer"

Enter the computername from the computer you want to manage, and click OK. The screen will now load the info from the remote computer.

Here you can unvold Groups to change the local groups such as Administrators, etc.

Do note that even though changing the groups, the changes will only becoming effective after a restart.

You can also remotely manage the registry. Start Regedit, and from menu file, select connect to remote machine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm doing this right now. Do you know of a way to do it to 100 computers simultaneously?

Comment: Write an instruction, and ask 100 people to do it at the same time. :P Kidding... But seriously, no. It would be a strain on the network if it was done to 100 pc's at the same time anyway. But perhaps it can be automated in some way using powershell...

Comment: @LPChip Downvoting. He already wrote he's doing it through the Computer Management...

Comment: @EliadTech From what he writes, there is no indication he uses the Computer Management method remote future. I read it as: He does it locally through Computer Management. Therefor I think your downvote is unjustified.

Comment: @LPChip Look at this comment: http://superuser.com/questions/847126/change-pc-local-group-members-from-active-directory-domain-controller/847140?noredirect=1#comment1117048_847126

Comment: @EliadTech that was posted AFTER I made my answer.

Comment: Well, sorry but the downvote can't be retracted now.

Answer (score -1):

You can either do it [with a script](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2007/08/30/powershell-script-to-add-remove-a-domain-user-to-the-local-administrators-group-on-a-remote-machine.aspx) (assuming the computers firewall won't block it) or [with a GPO](http://jimmoldenhauer.blogspot.co.il/2012/12/ad-2008r2-remove-users-from-local-admin.html) (if they all are under the same OU or group).

You can use both options for other groups as well (would require some editing respectively, of course).

Comment: Thank for the tip on doing it with a GPO. I had read about it but couldn't find anything clear in Spanish. I hope that article with pics do, but I'll see if it works on Windows 2003.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain?

Comment: Not mine. I can't vote since I don't have 15 points.